# How can I add space between these logos in list

Tags: html, css

I want to use social media icons and I'm trying to add space between them. I have then in `ul` and set each `li` to a different class. I know there's an easier way to go about this using `fontawesome` link and icons but I just wanted to see if this way works, I'm a beginner I just started coding 2 weeks ago.

I've tried the `light-height` and nothing happens:

```html
    <div class="container2">
        <ul class="contact1">
            <li class="contact2"><img src="facebook.png" alt="facebook" class="facebook"> </li>
            <li class="contact3"><img src="twitter.png" alt="twitter" class="twitter"> </li>
            <li class="contact4"><img src="instagram.png" alt="instagram" class="instagram"> </li>
            <li class="contact5"><img src="twitch.png" alt="twitch" class="twitch"> </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

```css
.contact1 {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%.-50%) 
}


 .contact1, .contact2, .contact3, .contact4, .contact5 {
    list-style: none;
    border: none;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 50px;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to use proper way of classes in html/css

Here is HTML

```
<div class="container2">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="facebook.png" alt="facebook" class="facebook"> </li>
        <li><img src="twitter.png" alt="twitter" class="twitter"> </li>
        <li><img src="instagram.png" alt="instagram" class="instagram"> </li>
        <li><img src="twitch.png" alt="twitch" class="twitch"> </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is CSS:

```
.container2 ul{
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    justify-content:space-around;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50% , -50%);
}

.container2 ul li{
    list-style: none;
    border: none;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 50px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend simply setting `margin-left` on every `.contact` that is not the first.

This can be achieved much easier by giving each element the *same* class of `.contact`, and then using the pseudo-selector `:not` in conjunction with the pseudo-selector `:first-of-type`. This can be seen in the following:

```css
.contact-container {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%.-50%)
}

.contact-container,
.contact {
  list-style: none;
  border: none;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 50px;
}

.contact:not(:first-of-type) {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="contact-container">
  <li class="contact"><img src="https://placehold.it/100" alt="facebook" class="facebook"> </li>
  <li class="contact"><img src="https://placehold.it/100" alt="twitter" class="twitter"> </li>
  <li class="contact"><img src="https://placehold.it/100" alt="instagram" class="instagram"> </li>
  <li class="contact"><img src="https://placehold.it/100" alt="twitch" class="twitch"> </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to add space, you can do it using flex box `justify-content:space-around` 

 and I edited your `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` in `.contact1`
see this snippet below

```css
.contact1 {
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    justify-content:space-around;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50% , -50%);
}


 .contact1, .contact2, .contact3, .contact4, .contact5 {
    list-style: none;
    border: none;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 50px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container2">
        <ul class="contact1">
            <li class="contact2"><img src="facebook.png" alt="facebook" class="facebook"> </li>
            <li class="contact3"><img src="twitter.png" alt="twitter" class="twitter"> </li>
            <li class="contact4"><img src="instagram.png" alt="instagram" class="instagram"> </li>
            <li class="contact5"><img src="twitch.png" alt="twitch" class="twitch"> </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```